# Why do two identical strings have a different length but the same binary value?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, collation, distinct

I am trying to return a distinct set of department names from a table - nothing special. However, when using the following query duplicates are displayed:

```
  select distinct department_name
    from dbo.departments;
```

I also tried:

```
  select distinct department_name
    from dbo.departments
group by department_name;
```

So this led me to believe that I might have hidden characters in the values and sure enough, when I checked the length of the strings they returned different values. So, I decided to locate the hidden characters using the function from [this question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655909/whats-the-best-way-to-identify-hidden-characters-in-the-result-of-a-query-in-sq). Strangely enough this only return SPACE. I then tried the following query and it made no difference at all:

```
select distinct ltrim(rtrim(department_name)) as department_name
  from dbo.departments;
```

Intrigued, I cast the values to `VARBINARY` and noticed that they have the exact same binary value, and performing a `DISTINCT` on the binary value does indeed produce a unique result set.

I have tried casting between `VARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` and to a different collation also (the values are in the same column, within the same database using Latin1_General_CI_AI). I really need to be able to get a distinct set from this table. Does anybody know what might be causing this issue?

**UPDATE**

After some further investigation, this issue seems to only happen for strings that end with the hex value `0xA000`. Any value in the column not ending with this character are fine.

**UPDATE 2**

If I remove the `0xA000` character from the string I can then apply `DISTINCT` as normal like so:

```
DECLARE @binary VARBINARY(8) = 0xA000;
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(8) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @binary);
 UPDATE dbo.departments
    SET department_name = REPLACE(department_name, @string, '');
```

But this won't work long term as users can update this table and I would need to adjust every query to do a replacement in the `WHERE` clause. I am using a workaround right now which is no more than using `MIN` to return the entry with the shortest length. This is less than ideal as the problem with distinct is also affecting most of the other language elements as well, for example `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, any window functions and `COUNT`.

Comment: Can you reproduce the situation at say https://dbfiddle.uk/ ?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: What does: `select distinct CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), department_name), 1) from dbo.departments;` show, still duplicates?

Comment: As a sanity check, run `DBCC CHECKTABLE(N'dbo.departments')`. If the binary values are actually the same, the only thing that comes to mind is the rows passed to the stream aggregate operator are out-of-order due to a problem with the index being scanned.

Comment: @DanGuzman I tried `DBCC CHECKTABLE` no anomalies.

Comment: @Lennart it still returns the same values.

Comment: @JoeObbish Thanks :-). I actually did not get notified from your comment. I only saw this in an email related to the [collation] tag. Either notifying someone like that only works if they are part of the discussion already or a moderator, OR maybe the issue was the space between my first and last name, since my username, like yours, doesn't have the space? Will need to try again some other time ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Good job investigating so far. Some initial notes:

1. I wouldn't worry about that function from the S.O. answer.
2. `RTRIM` and `LTRIM` only trim spaces, not white-space in general:

   ```
   SELECT RTRIM('A    ') + 'a';
   -- Aa

   SELECT RTRIM('A    ' + CHAR(9)) + 'a'; -- CHAR(9) = tab
   -- A        a
   ```
3. Adding `GROUP BY` (2nd query) doesn't change that query since it was implied in the first query ;-).
4. Whether `0xA000` is 2 `VARCHAR` characters or 1 `NVARCHAR` character, there does not seem to be any special behavior with this sequence of bytes for either datatype, using either `Latin1_General_CI_AI` or `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI`.

Still, something is amiss. You simply cannot have different length (or different anything) with the same binary value. How was length determined: `LEN` or `DATALENGTH`? Is it possible that the value got truncated somewhere in the testing so that it then *appeared* to be the same?

In order to help further, we need to know two things (please update the question with the results):

1. The exact datatype of the `department_name`. Please find via:

   ```
   SELECT typ.[name], col.*
   FROM   sys.columns col
   INNER JOIN sys.types typ
           ON typ.[user_type_id] = col.[user_type_id]
   WHERE  col.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.departments')
   AND    col.[name] = N'department_name';
   ```
2. The output of the following query:

   ```
   SELECT dept.department_name,
          LEN(dept.department_name) AS [name_chars],
          DATALENGTH(dept.department_name) AS [name_bytes],
          CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), dept.department_name) AS [name_hex]
   FROM   dbo.departments dept
   ORDER BY dept.department_name
   ```

   Just find a set of rows for a name that looks the same but is showing duplicates via `DISTINCT`.

For the moment, I can say that if you have character 0 (ASCII value 0, Code Point U+0000, `CHAR(0)`, `NCHAR(0)`) in your values then appearances can be deceiving since char(0) is the "null terminator" for strings. So neither it nor anything after it will be *displayed*, but it and everything after are still part of the string:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
  [Something] VARCHAR(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
);

INSERT INTO @Test ([Something])
VALUES ('Sometimes you' + CHAR(0) + 'feel like a nut');

INSERT INTO @Test ([Something])
VALUES ('Sometimes you' + CHAR(0) + 'feel like a nut');

INSERT INTO @Test ([Something])
VALUES ('Sometimes you' + CHAR(0) + 'don''t');

SELECT DISTINCT [Something],
       LEN([Something]) AS [Something_chars],
       DATALENGTH([Something]) AS [Something_bytes]
FROM   @Test;
/*
Something        Something_chars    Something_bytes
Sometimes you    19                 19
Sometimes you    29                 29
*/
```

Enjoy: [Peter Paul Almond Joy & Mounds - "Feel Like A Nut" (1980)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjVKUap1HgU)

---

**TEMPORARY UPDATE (WAITING FOR QUESTION TO BE UPDATED WITH QUERY OUTPUT):**

Based on this info from a comment:

> I used both LEN and DATALENGTH to perform the check. For two exact same strings I got (20,40) and (21,42) respectively.

it is clear that:

1. these are definitely different values, and
2. the datatype of the column is `NVARCHAR` (since `DATALENGTH` is twice `LEN`)

That means that the `0xA000` value is a single, UTF16LE character. Due to being Little Endian (bytes in reverse order), the actual Code Point is U+00A0. That character is:

[No-Break Space](https://unicode-table.com/en/00A0/)

As in our favorite HTML character: **&nbsp;**

All you need to do is remove those characters on the way into the DB, using:

```
REPLACE(@InputParam, NCHAR(0x00A0) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2, N'')
```

For example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),
      REPLACE(N'test' + NCHAR(0x00A0), NCHAR(0x00A0) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2, N'')
    );
```

To be clear, all of that work messing with `VARBINARY` and `VARCHAR`, etc is unnecessary.

> But this won't work long term as users can update this table and I would need to adjust every query to do a replacement in the `WHERE` clause.

True, updating every WHERE clause is not a workable solution. This is why you need to sanitize the input on the way in. There are a limited number of entry points for the data (INSERT / UPDATE procs for the UI, possibly some ETL processes), so it shouldn't be that bad. You can request that the developers strip out "bad" characters before they call the stored procedure(s), but there is no guarantee that they will, or that new code will, or that things won't change later, or that they will be able to fix ETL processes, etc.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, I used both `LEN` and `DATALENGTH` to perform the check. For two exact same strings I got (20,40) and (21,42) respectively. I will update my question with the output of your queries tomorrow when I am back in the office.

Comment: @Mr.Brownstone Thanks for that info. Please see temp update section. I look forward to seeing the query results :)

Comment: @Mr.Brownstone Hi there. Were you ever able to confirm my explanation? Did you see the updated part at the end of my answer? And, are you able to add the output of those 2 test queries to the question? Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for your help and apologies for the late response. The day that I raised this, and the subsequent few days after, the server was behaving very strange - returning incorrect results for queries (including my own) and I could not figure out what was happening. We started to notice severe disk problems and within a week the DAS crashed (controller problem) and we had to rebuild the databases. I can't be sure because I cannot replicate the problem anymore but I feel as though the issue may have been caused by the IO subsystem corrupting the database.